# Kendo change font-color in grid

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, kendo-ui, kendo-grid

Is it possible to change font-color of `Kendo` grid by some condition?
I hope I get data that can be recognized by jquery like:

```
if($("div td:contains('Online')")) {
         $("div :contains('Online')").css( "font-color", "Red" );
}
```

I have data get in database to show who is online/offline, but the two words are a little bit similar, so I hope I can change the text 'Online' to red. I can show data successfully, but I don't have any other tag(id or name, etc.) to make different from each data....

Is the only way I have to do is let each row have id or tags?
Can I just use `.contains` to find the object and change the color?

My html just simply:

```
<body>
<div id="grid"></div>
<script>
    $(function() {
        $("#grid").kendoGrid({
            dataSource: {
                transport: {
                    read: "data/userState.php"
                },
                error: function(e) {
                    alert(e.responseText);
                },
                schema: {
                    data: "results",
                    total: "Count"
                },
                pageSize: 10
            },
            columns: [{ field: "userAcc", title: "Account" },{ field: "state", title: "State" }],
            pageable: {
                refresh: true,
                pageSizes: true
            },
            height: 430,
            resizable: true
        });
        if($("#grid td:contains('Online')")) {
            $("#grid td:contains('Online')").css( "font-color", "Red" );
        }
    });

</script>
</div>
</body>
```

Comment: can you share the dom that is getting generated

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Get rid of the `if` statement and use a [column template](http://docs.kendoui.com/api/web/grid#configuration-columns.template) instead. You can wrap the value in a span and conditionally set its class to display red text based on your criteria.

Here's an example:

```
$("#grid").kendoGrid({
    // ...
    columns: [
        { field: "userAcc", title: "Account" },
        {
            field: "state",
            title: "State",
            template: "<span class='#if(state === \'Online\') {# red #}#'></span>"
        }
    ]
    // ...
});
```

..and your CSS class...

```
.red {
    color: red;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Sorry, I found my own answer.
That is, I need to use template( I am not familiar with it).
And just use template as:

```
<div id="grid"></div>
<script>
    $(function() {
        $("#grid").kendoGrid({
            dataSource: {
                transport: {
                    read: "data/userState.php"
                },
                error: function(e) {
                    alert(e.responseText);
                },
                schema: {
                    data: "results",
                    total: "Count"
                },
                pageSize: 10
            },
            columns: [{ field: "userAcc", title: "Account" },{ field: "state", title: "State", template: '#=SetColor(state)#' }],
            pageable: {
                refresh: true,
                pageSizes: true
            },
            height: 430,
            resizable: true
        });
    });
    function SetColor(state)
        {
            if(state=="Online")
                return "<font color=\"red\">"+state+"</font>";
            else
                return state;
        }
</script>
</div>
```

Use template to what field you want to change, and return text be decorated, and I promise that people want to make different from score or data like less than 60 can use the method, too!

Comment: The `<font>` tag is no longer supported as of HTML5. Use CSS to style the text color instead.

Answer (score 0):

Additional info for version 2014.1.528

Go Simple.

All you need to do is add a style attribute to the appropriate class

For a grid, add a style:

```
.k-grid .text-box {
    color: black !important;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Just use simple styles.

for text in data grid

```
.k-grid table {
    font-weight: bold !important;
}
```

for header text

```
.k-filter-row th, .k-grid-header th.k-header{
    font-weight: bold !important;
}
```